# How to run Phonegap App in tablet

Tags: android, cordova

I create a travel app in phonegap and run in AVD Manager but how to run this app in tablet

Comment: Which IDE are you using?

Comment: What is your tablet model? (Samsung, motorola or what)

Comment: Then, simply install your micromax tablet's driver software. Then, try to run with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simple you can also put your apk in your sdcard folder and double click on it apk file then it automatically install on your device.

Answer (score 0):

Just install the apk onto a device:

> adb install path/to/myapp.apk

http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html

Answer (score 0):

Create a new virtual device with a target higher then 3.2 and the skin set to built-in: WXGA800